# Get information from subject line of email

Tags: android

I am a long time admirer and first time asker on this wonderful board!

I am in the planning stages of developing an app for android but seem to be having trouble finding out if what i want to do is actually possible.

I know that most of it is but I am having trouble bringing it all together! basically for the part of the app i am up to i need to be able to read the subject line and body text of an email and save it into a variable to be called upon at a later date. Can anyone advise me on if this is possible and maybe on where i could get some example code it would be much appreciated! 
Thanks

Mike

Comment: So you recieve this email into your app?

Comment: if its easier to do it that way then yes, but i thought it may be able to read the information from the default mail application?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand from where are you expected to get an e-mail: from server or from locally configured mailbox?
- For reading mail from server you may use Java mail api (javax.mail.*)
- For saving subject for further reuse - SharedPreferences

Comment: i was hoping to get the mail from a locally configured mailbox if that is possible, although i would have no problem using the java mail api, i thought it might have been easier to use the local mail box